# How to return multiple value in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I want to return two array in this function(newton method). But when I run this script in matlab. It will only return the first array. How should I fix it?

```
    function [iter errorn]=Newton(func,dfunc,x0)
    i=1;
    solution=fzero(func,x0);
    while abs(x0-solution)>1e-06
      iter(i)=i;
      x0=x0-func(x0)./dfunc(x0);
      errorn(i)=abs(x0-solution);
      i=i+1;
    end
    end
```

The function is called by:

```
f1=@(x)x^3-2*x-5;
df1=@(x)3*x^2-2; 
[iter,y1N]=Newton(f1,df1,4)
```

But MATLAB returns an error: `too many arguments`

Comment: where is your function call?

Comment: check your function call how much **output variable** you assign to this function

Comment: f1=@(x)x^3-2*x-5;
df1=@(x)3*x^2-2;
[iter,y1N]=Newton(f1,df1,4);this is my function call but matlab has error "too many arguments" I can't figure out why@Karthick Rajan @Santhan Salai

Comment: the two output arrays are `iter` and `y1N`. what more do you want?

Comment: @YouweiZhu do you have a variable called "Newton" in the Workspace? Please try `which Newton` and verify that this is the path to your `Newton` function.

Comment: i checked the code which ran without any errors!!

Comment: @Santhan Salai I realised that matlab won't overwrite existing variable in this case.so I need to rename "iter and errorn"thanks a lot for verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add one more variable to the output of function call. Replace the variable name with the variable name of your problem.

```
[firstArray, secondArray] = Newton(func,dfunc,x0);
```

Check if the function is created as a separate function.m file and also it's visible to matlab (in the path).

Also refer to [hbaderts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4221706/hbaderts) comment - Same variable name as function name might override the function.

Comment: Thanks, realised that matlab won't overwrite existing variable, So I need to change variable name.